# How can I extract lines of text from a file?

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk, grep

I have a directory full of files and I need to pull the headers and footers off of them. They are all variable length so using head or tail isn't going to work. Each file does have a line I can search for, but I don't want to include the line in the results.

It's usually

```
*** Start (more text here)
```

And ends with

```
*** Finish (more text here)
```

I want the file names to stay the same, so I need to overwrite the originals, or write to a different directory and I'll overwrite them myself.

Oh yeah, it's on a linux server of course, so I have Perl, sed, awk, grep, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [flip flop!](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) ".." operator.

```
# flip-flop.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $start  = qr/^\*\*\* Start/;
my $finish = qr/^\*\*\* Finish/;

while ( <> ) {
    if ( /$start/ .. /$finish/ ) {
        next  if /$start/ or /$finish/;
        print $_;
    }
}
```

U can then use the -i perl switch to update your file(s) like so.....

```
 $ perl -i'copy_*' flip-flop.pl data.txt
```

...which changes data.txt but makes a copy beforehand as "copy_data.txt".

Comment: How would I get this (flipflop/range operator) to work with a variable rather than reading from a file. Say I have a `$variable = "dont want this part START i want this part instead FINISH";` ? Because I am having trouble getting the same effect when it is a variable as opposed to a file, your help is much appreciated, thanks –

Answer (score 2):

GNU coreutils are your friend...

```
csplit inputfile %^\*\*\* Start%1 /^\*\*\* Finish/ %% {*}
```

This produces your desired file as `xx00`.  You can change this behaviour through the options `--prefix`, `--suffix`, and `--digits`, but see the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/csplit-invocation.html#csplit-invocation) for yourself.  Since `csplit` is designed to produce a number of files, it is not possible to produce a file without suffix, so you will have to do the overwriting manually or through a script:

```
csplit $1 %^\*\*\* Start%1 /^\*\*\* Finish/ %% {*}
mv -f xx00 $1
```

Add loops as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

To get the **header**:

```
cat yourFileHere | awk '{if (d > 0) print $0} /.*Start.*/ {d = 1}'
```

To get the **footer**:

```
cat yourFileHere | awk '/.*Finish.*/ {d = 1} {if (d < 1) print $0}'
```

To get the file from **header to footer** as you want:

```
cat yourFileHere | awk '/.*Start.*/ {d = 1; next} /.*Finish.*/ {d = 0; next} {if (d > 0) print $0}'
```

There's one more way, with csplit command, you should try something like:

```
csplit yourFileHere /Start/ /Finish/
```

And examine files named 'xxNN' where NN is running number, also take a look at [csplit manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/csplit/).

Comment: I would be remiss if I failed to point out the unnecessary use of cat.
awk 'code' filename is much easier to type. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe? Start to Finish with not-delete.

```
$ sed -i '/^\*\*\* Start/,/^\*\*\* Finish/d!' *
```

or...less sure of it...but, if it works, should remove the Start and Finish lines as well:

```
$ sed -i -e '/./,/^\*\*\* Start/d' -e '/^\*\*\* Finish/,/./d' *
```

`d!` may depend on the build of `sed` you have -- not sure.
And, I wrote that entirely on (probably poor) memory.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Perl hack, not tested.  I am not fluent enough in sed or awk to get this effect with them, but I would be interested in how that would be done.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Tie::File;
my $Filename=shift;  
tie my @File, 'Tie::File', $Filename or die "could not access $Filename.\n";  
while (shift @File !~ /^\*\*\* Start/) {};  
while (pop @File !~ /^\*\*\* Finish/) {};  
untie @File;
```

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution that overwrites the original file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ni
if(my $num = /^\*\*\* Start/ .. /^\*\*\* Finish/) {
    print if $num != 1 and $num + 0 eq $num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the examples in [perlfaq5: How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How_do_I_change_dele) may help. You'll have to adapt them to your situation. Also, Leon's flip-flop operator answer is the idiomatic way to do this in Perl, although you don't have to modify the file in place to use it.