# How to Extract lines from file using regex and push to variable/array in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for help to extract particular line which has "Start" and "End" Keyword and 
Input file:

```
adfafaf
adfafafas
adfafaf
Detail=Process Start Time   : TIMESTAMP '2014-02-14 01:20:58.918757'
AAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDD
End Time                    : TIMESTAMP '2014-02-14 01:21:49.520818'
adffffffff
adfffff
adfff
```

Desired output:
Below lines are required to moved to string/array.

```
Detail=Process Start Time   : TIMESTAMP '2014-02-14 01:20:58.918757'
AAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCC
DDDDDDDD
End Time                    : TIMESTAMP '2014-02-14 01:21:49.520818'
```

Comment: what's wring with just iterating over the file line-by-line and when a line matches, you push it to the array (or do whatever you want with it)? Takes about 5 lines of code

Comment: `@array = eval('sub { grep /Start/../End/, @_ }')->( <inputfile> )`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212799/how-do-i-extract-lines-between-two-line-delimiters-in-perl

Comment: @ysth, How that's different than `@array = grep /Start/../End/, <inputfile>`?

Comment: @ikegami: not, if you only ever run it once or there is never a Start without an End

Comment: @ysth, I see. You'd want to use your version inside of a subroutine to make sure the iterator is reset. I don't think the `sub` is necessary for that, though. `my @array = eval('grep /Start/../End/, <inputfile>'); die $@ if $@;` should do. But wouldn't be simpler just to avoid `..`?

Comment: @ikegami: yes, it would be simpler to avoid .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets your lines

```
if ($subject =~ m/^[^\n]*?Start.*?End[^\n]+/sm) {$result = $&;}
```

It is dot-all mode so the `.*` can match over multi lines. To stop at the end of the last line we use `[^\n]+` which match all character except newline.

Comment: you want `[^\n]` instead of the first `.` (or use `.` everywhere but `(?s:.*)` in the middle)